# Example of noetherian module non-uniquely expressible as sum of indecomposable submodules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, noetherian

If $M$ is a noetherian module then it can be written as a finite sum of indecomposable submodules of $M$. The same can be concluded if we assume instead $M$ to be artinian. If we ask for both $M$ to be noetherian and artinian, then we can conclude that such a decomposition is unique in the sense of Krull-Schmidt theorem.

My question is:

> What is an example of a noetherian module expressible as a finite sum of indecomposable modules in at least two nonequivalent ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are simple examples. You can find one given by R.G. Swan [here](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102946603).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is much simpler than the family of counterexamples that I found previously. I'm talking about those presented here https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=OdNJAAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @Pipicito I was aware (and not content) of that examples.

Comment: What does the notation $($something with $x$ and $y)_{(x,y)}$ means in the article by Swan? I am referring to $A = (R[x,y] / (x^3 - x^2 + y^2) )_{(x,y)}$...

Comment: @Pipicito This is the localization at the prime ideal $(x,y)$.